# How do I implement Server Sent Events in PHP?

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I had set up a server sent event script with php and a while loop, I did not want for the script to have to keep closing and have to repoll so I put it all in a while loop.

The issue was that the script was getting stuck and I had to abandon that route and I went with a node.js websocket backend instead.

My question is, if I ever went back to making a server sent event php script, how do I implement it?
`while` loops do not seem to cut it as it hangs the script, and if it is just connecting and disconnecting every second, it is no different than long polling, so how do I create a PHP script that will not hang, while also sending over the SSE messages?

Comment: You could put a `sleep()` in the loop to loosen it up.

Comment: @Musa I did that to no avail. It still hung.

Comment: What the problem with this example? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Sending_events_from_the_server

Comment: @chumkiu I have tried that. It hangs.

Comment: also with `ignore_user_abort(false);` ?

Comment: @chumkiu and `set_time_limit(0)`

Comment: Do you have on output buffering or mod_deflate?

Answer (score 5):

You seemed to have issue on php output buffering. Try adding these line to the end of your `while` loop:

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

This should disable the output buffering.

**EDIT** You can also terminates the script after some time (i.e. 10mins) to reduce server load.

I've created a library for you to do it very easily. Check it [here](https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php).

**Second Edit**
Do you have a reverse proxy such as nginx or varnish? This may be the reason because the proxy tries to cache the content of the output but the SSE script never ends until you stop it so the whole thing hangs. Other things that captures the output may have similar results such as mod_deflate.

**Third edit**
If you have a reverse proxy, you can try to turn off caching to allow SSE to work.

There are another ways in PHP to disable output buffering. See the code below:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<ob_get_level();$i++){
    ob_end_flush();
}
@apache_setenv('no-gzip',1);
@ini_set('implict_flush',1);
ob_implict_flush(true);
```

Comment: This is consistent with an answer I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469396/how-to-implement-event-listening-in-php/8660897#8660897