# websockets and PHP basics and initiatives

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

I have to built a multilayer game using web-sockets. For this I have a a shared web server with Apache. Browser is not an issue I am building for modern browsers only.
I tried few example `PHP` and web-socket source code but no luck.
What do I need to do?
And also how to enable the PHP `socket_create` function? Already enables `php_sockets` extension in the `php.ini` and also the `php_sockets.dll` exists in the extension directory.
When I call `socket_create` function php says that this function is undefined.

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When I view the phpInfo the socket support is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the command prompt was using a different configuration file for PHP.

Apache (or from the WAMP's interface) uses a php.ini that is located at:

```
 [WAMP_DIRECTORY]\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
```

If you will open this file, you may notice that the line extension=php_sockets.dll is already commented out.

Unfortunately, the CLI or command line interface is using a different configuration file which is located at:

```
 [WAMP_DIRECTORY]\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.ini
```

In order to resolve it, you should comment out the line extension=php_sockets.dll and save it. Run the program after to see if the websockets again are already up and working.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee WebSocket support in the browser then use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me). It won't run within Apache, but as a separate process.

There are other options available too - see the [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

Questions related to WebSocket + PHP have been asked a number of times on SO. I'd recommend doing a search for best solutions and known gotchas when using Apache, PHP + WebSocket. Here's are a couple of good starting question with some additional links in the answers:

- [Is native PHP support for Web Sockets available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203443/is-native-php-support-for-web-sockets-available/12204603)
- [Efficient reloading data / pushing data from server to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122911/efficient-reloading-data-pushing-data-from-server-to-client/16171798#16171798)