# How to fetch real time data from mysql db react native

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to react native. I was doing fine with `fetch()` until I fall into this problem:


I have a chat screen. (**For clearness: I am using gifted-chat**). So, when people enter in a conversation, I call a fetch and get all messages from my database(**mysql db, php script**). Then, I save to a state called `data`.
At last, I show the messages. [It's pretty easy till now]. But the problem reveals itself when someone send me a message. The data is not updating. I know why this happens - it is not updating the state with the updated data because no further `fetch()` is done.
I planned to call `fetch()` with an interval like 1 second to get latest data but I think, this is not a good idea. Calling so much `fetch()` is harmful surely.

Then, I think about **real time** data. My question is, how can get real time data from my mysql database using react native? I need to get real time data and update the state. But is it possible? Or how to do it?

I am not too older and very new to react native. Please forgive my problems and help me to get through this.

My snack: https://snack.expo.io/@nothingtosay/laughing-carrot

**NOTE: I WILL NOT USE FIREBASE BECAUSE MY MAIN WEBSITE IS BASED ON MYSQL AND IT IS RUNNING**
\

UPDATE: I have start using Socket.io to retrieve real time data. So thanks all. I don't need solution any more....

Comment: see if that helps you further https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501154/5193536

Comment: nbk Yeah, I already mentioned it. But is this a good idea to fetch again and again with an interval? Should I use it?

Comment: the mentioned push btechnology will be more fitting, but it is not well docomented and you will have a steep learning curve to implement it. sp for te first approach, you must test it with a lot of simulated clients, if the server can hold it.