# Loop at Biggest ID unless new bigger ID found

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've got this running thanks to one of you.

Concept is that this database will constantly be inserted with new entries and displaying them, *though* we need to have a plan be if there is a pause in user entries, loop it at current content.

*But*, now I have a difficulty to loop at the current row while there is no new ID.

What this code is doing is constantly refreshing every 30sec and adding 1 to the row so it slowly displays content.

Thing is, it will continue to retrieve even though there is no such ID.
How do we get it to loop at current ID until next biggest ID is avail then display?

And how do we include the `fadeOut` before previous ID content and `fadeIn` new ID content?

```
<?php
        //connection via 
        require 'config.php';

        $conn = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

        // Create connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        if (isset($_REQUEST["next_row"])) { 
            $myrow = 0;
            $myrow = $_REQUEST["next_row"];
        } if(isset($_REQUEST["next_row"]) >=$myrow) {
            $myrow = $_REQUEST["next_row"]; }
        //else { $myrow = 0; }

        echo '<form id=myform> <input type=text name="next_row" value="'.($myrow * 1+1).'"> </form>';

        //$toprow = "SELECT ID FROM demo WHERE ID DESC ";
        //if ($toprow == $myrow) {
        //    $myrow = $_REQUEST["next_row"]-1;
        //}

        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo` ORDER BY `ID` DESC ";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET ". $myrow;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<div id="main">';
                echo '  <p>"'.$row["Comment"].'"<br>';
                echo '  <span>'.$row["Name"].'</span><br>';
                echo '  <span>'.$row["Org"].'</p>';
                echo "</div>";
            }

        } //if ($result->num_rows >= $sql) {
            //$myrow = $_REQUEST["next_row"]-1;
        //}
        else {
                //$myrow = 0;
                //echo "0 results";
                echo '<div id="main">';
                echo '  <p>';
                echo '      Welcome to Sydney Brenner Event!';
                echo '  </p>';
                echo "</div>";
            }
    $conn->close();        
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#myform').submit(); }, 29000); 
        </script>
```

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171798/267540

Comment: Its not a chat Group, its a send and post to wall comments remarks.

Comment: So what's your point?

Comment: what is your point? I mentioned that my database will receive entries from users and this page will post it but it will even grab rows that do not exist; need it to loop and current content until new entry is added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement basic "Long Polling"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-to-implement-basic-long-polling)

Comment: Similar though not duplicate. it doesn't even look close to this code, how do I include that function?

Comment: after analysing. it is different